# Low Events …. How do I set repeating events

Tags: low-events

How do I set repeating events. If I have a dance show and it plays for three consecutive nights, how do I display that. If I put end date in (:duration), its says 3 days and 1 hour.

I what it to wright it 3 times within one channel entry.

Example:

Event Title

November 4, 2014, 8pm
 November 5, 2014, 8pm
 November 6, 2014, 8pm

Event Description

---

I am stuck .... I got everything else figured out, first time user.

Best, 
Seeingis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Robson is right: Low Events doesn't support recurring events.

Low Events uses this definition to determine what an 'event' is: **an event is a single entry with a single start date/time and optional end date/time**. According to that definition, you're actually looking at 3 events (with the same title).

There are 2 ways to get what you're describing. The simplest solution is to just mention the three different dates in the description field of a single entry. The single entry can then span 3 days.

The other solution is to use Relationships. Create 2 channels: Events and Occurrences. The Events channel contains event descriptions, without dates. The Occurrences channel contains the Low Events field and a relationships field where you can choose an Event. In your templates, you then list the Occurrences and display the event title and description using the relationship tags and vars.

Answer (score 0):

Low Events doesn't support recurrence.

From [its own website](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-events):

> Low Events [...] keeps things simple by not having repeatable events and their obtuse rules...